# Bash command substitution with a variable

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I'm new to bash scripting and I've been learning as I go with a small project I'm taking on. However, I've run into a problem that I cannot seem to get past.

I have a variable that I need to include in a command. When ran directly in the shell (with the variable manually typed), the command returns the expected result. However, I can't get it to work when using a variable.

So, if I manually run this, it correctly returns 0 or 1, depending if it is running or not.

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -c ProcessName
```

However, when I try to embed that into this while clause, it always evaluates to 0 because it's not searching for the correct text.

```
while [ `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -c {$1}` -ne 0 ]
do
  sleep 5
done
```

Is there a way I can accomplish this? I've tried a myriad of different things to no avail. I also tried using the **$()** syntax for command substitution, but I had no luck with that either.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have braces in your while loop's test, but not in your example? And does $1 have the correct value?

Comment: I put the braces in the while loop because I thought I needed them there to signify the variable. That may be incorrect, but removing them does not resolve the problem for me. And yes, $1 has the correct value. I added `echo $1` right before the while statement and it is correct.

Comment: If you need to use curly braces, the dollar sign goes before the opening one and it's a good ideas to quote it, too: `"${1}"`. Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) for some useful information.

Comment: You might also want to look at the [parameter expansion section of the bash man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). The upshot is that `$var` is the same as `${var}`; the latter is for cases like `${var}_suffix`, since `$var_suffix` would be interpreted like `${var_suffix}`. As Dennis says, the `$` is always first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that instead of `{$1}` you mean `"$1"`.  Also, you can just do `pgrep -c "$1"` instead of the two pipes.

In addition, there's also no need to compare the output of `grep -c` with `0`, since you can just see if the command failed or not.  So, a much simplified version might be:

```
while pgrep "$1" > /dev/null
do
    sleep 4
done
```

Comment: I replaced `{$1}` with `"$1"` but that does not work either. I'm going to look over this to make sure I'm not missing something...

Comment: @grt3kl: Sorry, I got the sense of what you're trying to do wrong - I now realise that you're trying to sleep while a certain process is running, not to sleep until it starts.  So, I've changed the example from `until pgrep "$1"` to `while pgrep "$1"`, which certainly works for me here.

Comment: Can you explain what `pgrep "$1" > /dev/null` does? Actually, I understand it except for the arithmetic comparison. If I wanted to do the opposite (i.e., sleep while a certain process is not running), would it just be `pgrep "$1" <= /dev/null` or something different altogether?

Comment: `>` here isn't a comparison - it says to redirect the standard output of the command to the special file `/dev/null`, which basically means to throw it away.  I added that because otherwise you'd see the output of the `pgrep` command whenever it runs.

Comment: I discovered that my problem was a bit more complex than I thought, but this answer is what led me to a solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should really use `-C` with `ps` rather than the messy pipes if you're using the full process name. If you're interested in substring matching, then your way is the only thing I can think of.