# Shell: insert variable into a command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, unix

I'm trying to find a way the use a variable in this command to replace -10 with n_days var:

```
   n_days= -10
   date_prefix=$(date -d '-10 day' +%Y/%m/%d)
```

I tried this way but it didn't work:

```
   date_prefix=$(date -d '${n_days} day' +%Y/%m/%d)
```

Comment: Change single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a space in a variable assignment give an error in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41748466/608639), [Expansion of variable inside single quotes in a command in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13799789/608639), [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067266/608639), [Bash command substitution with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4935833/608639), etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things:

1. Declare your variable properly (there is a space in your example)
2. Use double quotes in place of single quotes to allow the variable to be interpolated

So:

```
n_days=-10
date_prefix=$(date -d "$n_days day" +%Y/%m/%d)
```